# How do I change the time zone Steam uses?

Tags: steam

When I receive Steam messages, the shown time that the message was received is inaccurate. It's always 3 hours earlier than I actually received the message. For example, if someone sends me a message at 9:30, Steam will say I got the message at 6:30.

I guess this is because Steam thinks I want the Pacific timezone, when I really want Eastern. Is there a way to solve this? Or, is this caused by some other phenomenon? (And is there still a way to solve this?) I couldn't find anything in the settings that looked like it would affect this, and my download location is set appropriately.

Troubleshooting:

- The sender is definitely in the same time zone as me.
- My OS time zone is set properly.
- The download server I have set in Steam is in the same time zone as me.

Comment: I found multiple threads with the same issue and no solutions. In many cases it seems that if you are offline, the messages are time stamped with the senders local time, rather than receivers.

Comment: What download server is your steam assigned to? Something far away? Or is the location of that server PDT instead of EDT?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness The download server is set appropriately; I could drive there in under an hour.

Comment: That does not mean it couldnt be a different timezone.. but what server is it? So I could try and use that one for comparison. edit: I just changed to a US Server and I still have the same time.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness It's certainly the same time zone as me. It's the US-New York server.

Comment: @StrixVaria DOuble checked, still got the same time in my chats. I changed my local time and the time stamps changed only on my side. Do you have a secondary clock in windows set up?

Comment: Have you set your country in steam profile?

Comment: @KimMinseo Country doesn't make a difference because it's optional (I tried changing it).

Comment: Oh ok... then I really don't know what to do.

Comment: Just wondering, `For example, if someone sends me a message at 9:30, Steam will say I got the message at 6:30.` Where you both online at the time when the message was sent?